# MongoDB WriteConcert, and Write timeout not working

Tags: mongodb

I'm currently using MongoDB 2.2.30.
I'm trying to limit the time that MongoDB waits for a response from the DB.

Currently, if  I disconnect the internet, and make an Insert, it basically waits forever, and I never receive an error.

I would like the operation to abort after a certain amount of time, lets say 5 secs.

My connection:

```
let settings = {
    connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
    reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
    reconnectInterval: 1000, 

    w: 1,
    wtimeout: 5000
}
let db = await MongoClient.connect(connectionString, settings);
```

Writing operation:

```
let user = {username: "samuel", password: "aStrongPassword!", email: "me@me.com"}
const result = await db.collection('users').insertOne(user);
return result.insertedId;
```

Testing this, I get the same results as without `w` and `wtimeout`.
Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: I'm getting the same results.

Comment: Sorry, I had pay a bit more attention to your code. `reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,` basically says to keep trying to reconnect  forever. Set it to 5 to get connection error after 5 seconds (given reconnectInterval remain 1 sec).

Comment: I did it intentionally because I want it to keep trying to reconnect forever, According to the docs "`wtimeout` causes write operations to return with an error after the specified limit, even if the required write concern will eventually succeed", that's why I used it, I just want it to try to perform the operation for 5 seconds, even if the connection is good.

Comment: wtimeout works purely on serverside, and triggers an error if the `w` members of replica were not updated within this period of time. When you 'disconnect the internet', server has no chance to feed back to the client whether write was successful or not.

Comment: @AlexBlex I understand, thank you, so I need to make my connection last/try to connect for 5 seconds.